# Not able to generate php artisan key after copying .env file

Tags: php, laravel

i had unextracted a project file from git and i want to use it in the local server but when i copy paste the .env and run the command to generate the key. their seems to be an error.

i tried installing auto-dumpload command but it doesnt seem to work

```
php artisan key:generate
```

> ErrorException  :
>   file_get_contents(C:\Users\Anifz\React\getfyt-webapp-master.env):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> at
>   C:\Users\Anifz\React\getfyt-webapp-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\KeyGenerateCommand.php:96
>        92|     {
>        93|         file_put_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath(), preg_replace(
>        94|             $this->keyReplacementPattern(),
>        95|             'APP_KEY='.$key,
>        96|             file_get_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath())
>        97|         ));
>        98|     }
>        99|
>       100|     /**
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1
>   file_get_contents("C:\Users\Anifz\React\getfyt-webapp-master.env")
>         C:\Users\Anifz\React\getfyt-webapp-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\KeyGenerateCommand.php:96
>
> 2
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\KeyGenerateCommand::writeNewEnvironmentFileWith("base64:psZqTYKIKLRKPOhzVWUWZ2pny7A/nb4ArWeklrKWofE=")
>         C:\Users\Anifz\React\getfyt-webapp-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\KeyGenerateCommand.php:80
>
> Please use the argument -v to see more details.

Comment: What is this file you are trying to open? `getfyt-webapp-master.env`  in the root of your laravel project just create a .env file that's all.

Comment: Check in `bootstrap/app.php` if there is a call to this method `$app->useEnvironmentPath()` wich changes the path of the environment file.

Comment: Seems you need to create a `.env` file - you can copy the `example.env` file from here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example and rename it to `.env`. Note: When cloning projects from repo's you always need to create your `env` file

Answer (score 1):

The Following are the steps that you should follow -

1. extract the project.
2. copy `.env.example` to `.env`
3. run `composer install`
4. then run `php artisan key:generate`

Answer (score 0):

I think .env  file not exist ,if exist file copy one from .env.examle and set name as .env

Exec this code

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Maybe u want clear cache if want it u can with below code

```
php artisan cache:clear
```